# Re: TSA Precheck. Does this apply to international flights?

Tags: international-travel, children, pre-clearance, tsa-precheck

I am American. I will be traveling from Shanghai back to the US. Can I get TSA Precheck while abroad?

My 1-year-old son is also American. Same situation and question. My wife is Chinese. Same question.

Comment: What were you hoping to achieve with TSA Pre? Is your wife a LPR in the US?

Comment: There is no real advantage to TSA Pre on flights to the USA.  It would only be beneficial on your way home.

Comment: So you are both saying that it is only beneficial on outbound flights not incoming flights? I thought that it would help at customs. It was mentioned on the TSA website and CBP website.

Comment: TSA Pre is for security check at the start of your flight. At US immigration and customs you'd want either Global Entry, US Mobile passport (but your wife can't use it), or Nexus perhaps. With Global Entry/Nexus you'd get TSA Pre thrown in

Comment: The only place TSA Pre might help at immigration would be post entry security before going to your connecting flight.  But I haven't seen it at the airports I frequent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TSA Precheck only applies to security checkpoints operated by the US Transportation Security Administration (and, [at some US airports](https://www.tsa.gov/for-industry/screening-partnerships), checkpoints operated by contractors on behalf of TSA). At non-US airports, another country's airport security authorities are responsible, and they do not recognize TSA Precheck.

If you simply wish to enroll in TSA Precheck overseas for your use when you are in the US, you will need to complete the application and visit [an enrollment center](https://universalenroll.dhs.gov/locator?serviceCode=11115V). As best I can tell, there are no enrollment centers outside the United States. A workaround is to apply for another Trusted Traveler program, such as [Global Entry](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry), which speeds your entry through US immigration and grants TSA Precheck benefits. There are [Global Entry enrollment centers](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/enrollment-centers) in Canada and Qatar. If those don't work for you, you'll need to enroll after you return to the US. You can do that in the immigration area when your flight gets in with [Enroll on Arrival](https://thepointsguy.com/guides/how-to-enroll-in-global-entry-on-arrival/) now (this requires you to go through the application process and be conditionally approved in advance, you can't just roll up and do it), though the benefits like TSA Precheck won't take effect immediately, so you wouldn't be able to use it for a connecting flight right then and there.

Note that TSA Precheck membership is [only open to US Citizens and Lawful Permanent Residents](https://www.dhs.gov/trusted-traveler-comparison-chart) (other non-members may receive Precheck benefits on their boarding passes, though that [will be happening less often now](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/01/31/this-tsa-travel-perk-may-be-ending-for-some.html)). Global Entry also allows citizens of [some other countries](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/eligibility), but not Chinese nationals.

Comment: Need to be US citizen or LPR for TSA Pre I believe.

Comment: @Berwyn Good point. Updated.

Comment: Non-US citizens/PR's can get Pre-Check on a random basis, they just can't apply for it.

Comment: You don't need to be a US citizen to use TSA Pre, but perhaps you do to apply for it.  My wife (non-usa, non-lpr) gets it when we travel together.

Comment: @Tom they're supposedly [cutting back on offering it to non-members](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/01/31/this-tsa-travel-perk-may-be-ending-for-some.html), though I don't know how much that will impact people traveling together, especially if one traveler is a member.

Comment: I know the frequent flyer freebies are decreasing.  Folks who are occasionally elite level or in bottom tiers are not getting TSA Pre much, but folks who maintain high status year after year seem to still be in the gold.  Which makes sense, since if you fly 50K to 100K or more per year, year after year, without incident you are a fairly low risk traveler.

Comment: I think the reduction in access to "non-members" will not affect those who obtain their membership through a programme like Global Entry. From reading the article they are reducing the number of random pre-check ticks they give out to completely unverified passengers. So as a non-US citizen you can still obtain Pre-Check through these other routes.

Comment: @Tom follow up to your comment. Your wife gets pre-check since you have it? How exactly does that work?

Comment: @JeffreyRust Besides people who have signed up, the TSA can also give Pre Check to people according to risk formula they've cooked up. The more you fly, the more likely you are to get it and the rubs off on the people who are flying with you. Other criteria such as age and nationality will be included too. Every so often the TSA say they're going to get rid of that part in order to encourage people to sign up, but it hasn't happened yet

Comment: @JeffreyRust - Couldn't tell you exactly how it transfers over, as TSA doesn't reveal its logic/formula.  I just know that my wife and/or daughter get TSA Pre when we travel together on a single booking or linked bookings.

Comment: @Tom it may not be "transferring over": my wife often gets it despite being a non-US citizen and non-LPR, and belonging to no trusted traveler program. She also didn't get it from traveling with me; I am a US citizen, but I also belong to no trusted traveler program, and I only got it once.  If anything, it looks like *her* favorable profile may have rubbed off on *me* that time.

Comment: My partner booked tickets and got my birthdate wrong so the precheck didn't go through. When I got it fixed at the airport, the airline employee said that all members of my party would also get it. That's obviously true for my 2 kids (until they're 12) per TSA, but my partner does not have precheck. This was October 2016.

Comment: My wife and I often get pre-check outbound from the US despite not having ever applied.  We took a trip with some of her relatives--here on a B2, not LPR or citizen and they all got pre-check on the one flight we took.  I'm pretty sure it's age plus a light load at pre-check that does it.

Comment: @phoog - I know on at least one occasion it definitely was transferred over from me.  Earlier this month we flew from the states back to Thailand, my wife & daughter were on FF tix, I was on a separate paid tix.  The initial check in agent somehow unlinked the bookings and the boarding passes came without Pre for them, but mine had it.  At the hub airport I had the seats adjusted and the gate agent relinked the bookings after we discovered they weren't linked anymore, then on all the new boarding passes they both had Pre ... but we were already through security :(

Comment: I don't think this had started yet when you originally wrote this answer, but there's now another option for enrolling in Global Entry: You can now [enroll on arrival](https://thepointsguy.com/guides/how-to-enroll-in-global-entry-on-arrival/) at certain U.S. international airports. You still need to apply online and get the conditional approval first, though.

Comment: @reirab Good point. That's newer. I'll add a note. It doesn't take effect immediately though, so you couldn't enroll on arrival and immediately get precheck for a connecting flight beyond the random "sometimes you just get precheck for no reason" stuff.

Comment: @ZachLipton They actually do give you your PASSID at the interview and it's ready to use, but, yeah, I'm not sure if you'd be able to use it on a connecting flight a few minutes later. I'm not sure if there's a delay between CBP's systems and TSA's systems being updated. At the very least, you'd have to add your PASSID to your reservation and reprint your boarding pass in order to do that.